# Rewrite URL with all dynamic parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic, url-rewriting

I am pretty new to .htaccess rewrites, and I'm trying to create rules to dynamically rewrite the URLs.

For example, say the user enters the following URL:

This is my base URL  -

```
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/
```

Now the URL could be like

```
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/category OR
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/category/abc OR
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/xyz  OR
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anythingNewAgainHere/xyz OR
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/anything OR 
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/anything/anything...
```

Therefore I want to make it like

```
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/category.html
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/category/abc.html
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/xyz.html
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anythingNewAgainHere/xyz.html 
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/anything.html 
http://lptpl.info/oCatalog/anything/anything/anything.html  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just trying to add dummy `.html` extension. Have this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(oCatalog/.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```